# Folder specified in "./configre --prefix" stays empty

Tags: ios, linux, build

I'm trying to build `libimobile_device` in order to use `ios_webkit_debug_proxy`.
I'm following this tut:

[tutorial](http://www.davidemontersino.com/development-en/web-development/2014/09/how-to-use-ipads-web-inspector-on-ubuntu/)

Everything workd fine since I get to this

```
~/Downloads/libplist-1.11$ ./configure --prefix=/<home-folder>/ios-proxy/

checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
[....]
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating libcnary/Makefile
config.status: creating src/Makefile
config.status: creating include/Makefile
config.status: creating tools/Makefile
config.status: creating cython/Makefile
config.status: creating test/Makefile
config.status: creating libplist.pc
config.status: creating libplist++.pc
config.status: creating doxygen.cfg
config.status: creating config.h
config.status: config.h is unchanged
config.status: executing depfiles commands
config.status: executing libtool commands

Configuration for libplist 1.11:
-------------------------------------------

Install prefix: .........: /<home-folder>/ios-proxy
Python bindings .........: no

Now type 'make' to build libplist 1.11,
and then 'make install' for installation.
```

I've got no error but ios-proxy still remains empty.
Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's anything like the thousand-odd `configure` scripts I've ever run then what you are asking for is to install the binaries into the specified location, so:

```
$ make install
```

is probably what you want.

Comment: `Make` and `make install` are the next steps. So it's normal that until here ios-proxy folder is empty?

Comment: @Nemus Yes. It's customary to build the binaries as a non-privileged user and only become root when installing.  Prefix would normally be `/usr/local`, which is not world-writable.